# How to make colour in python without downloading anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i would like to find out if there is any way to code in colour to python? Ive researched colorama and stuff like that but unfortunately i cant download anything at school to add colour to my python program. I am trying to make a grid for a treasure hunt game, and i would like to colour in some of the tiles

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python

Comment: Could you provide more details? What do you want to color? The output on the console?

Comment: Yeah, wanted to colour the output on the IDLE. We use IDLE at school, and are unfortunately stuck with it as the python console is extremely buggy for unknown reasons

Answer (score 0):

What colorama (and similar) libraries do under the hood is print 'ansi escape sequences' to generate terminal colors. you can read more about these special sequences here:

http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/ansi_escape_sequences.htm